# Forcing a save as dialogue from any web browser from JSF application

Tags: java, jsf

I've created a JSF application, and I want to embed a link in a page which when clicked causes the backing bean to marshall out some xml and force the opening of a save-as download dialogue box so the user can choose a location to save the file.  I've already written the JAXB code.

How is this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Set the HTTP `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`. This will pop a *Save As* dialogue. You can do that using [`HttpServletResponse#setHeader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). You can obtain the HTTP servlet response from under the JSF hoods by [`ExternalContext#getResponse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResponse%28%29).

In JSF context, you only need to ensure that you call [`FacesContext#responseComplete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete()) afterwards to avoid `IllegalStateException`s flying around.

Kickoff example:

```
public void download() throws IOException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    response.reset(); // Some JSF component library or some Filter might have set some headers in the buffer beforehand. We want to get rid of them, else it may collide.
    response.setContentType("application/xml"); // Check http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types for all types. Use if necessary ServletContext#getMimeType() for auto-detection based on filename.
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"name.xml\""); // The Save As popup magic is done here. You can give it any filename you want, this only won't work in MSIE, it will use current request URL as filename instead.

    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(getYourXmlAsInputStream());
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
        for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        close(output);
        close(input);
    }

    facesContext.responseComplete(); // Important! Else JSF will attempt to render the response which obviously will fail since it's already written with a file and closed.
}
```

Comment: thanks very much indeed. I put the code in and now, when I click the link, the (FF) browser replaces the current page with a page containing the file contents rather than popping up a download window.  What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Try in another browsers (IE, Chrome) as well or restart FF with a clean profile. It may happen that a webbrowser is configured to be the default application for XML files and that XML files should be opened automatically when downloaded.

Comment: Oh, also ensure that this isn't an asynchronous (ajaxical) request, but just a synchronous ("plain vanilla") request. I.e. just use `h:commandLink` or `h:commandButton`, but not RichFaces, Ajax4jsf, IceFaces, etc ajaxical-powered `UICommand` components.

Comment: I've specified save for xml file types in FF, and switched to `h:commandButton` and when I click the button now, the whole page reloads and no save dialog appears. The app will not be supported in IE or Chrome (can't even test with them).  Not sure where to look now.

Comment: Is it inside a `h:form`? Is the method actually invoked? Walk through [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) to check one and other.

Comment: @BalusC I'm using a CDI bean and instead of a BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream I use the getWriter() to write my XML string to the response since I have it an a String variable. The method is being called when the application runs but no dialog for downloading is appearing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `content-disposition: attachment` HTTP header

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you need to force the writer to send the contents to the client by calling `response.getWriter().flush();` before closing the writer. This prompted the save as popup in my case.

Comment: This is only necessary when the request-response chain contains a broken custom `HttpServletResponseWrapper` implementation which returns a broken custom writer. For the standard Servlet and JSF implementations this is absolutely not necessary. The solution should be to fix that wrapper/writer implementation and not to manually flush the writer everywhere in the code.