# Java Web application, how to let a client save a generated .txt file?

Tags: java, file, download

I have a JSF Web application, and at some point i present the client a big chunk of information, I want to have a save as link, that allows the client to save this information on his computer as a .txt file.

Information on how to achieve this or a good tutorial would be great.

Comment: @Emboss It is really not that big, less than 2000 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428039/download-a-file-with-jsf) work for you? You probably would need to set the ContentType to "application/octet-stream", otherwise the client's browser will display your text file instead of offering the option to "Save as".

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet may be to have that link actually generate an Ajax call to generate the text file and set it as the `src` attribute of an `iframe` on the page. That will trigger (I think) the file download box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could this be done without using ajax?