# JSF managed upload bean?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, upload, multipart, managed-bean

I have an upload routine which is working for servlets. Now I was trying to put this routine in a jsf managed bean like this:

```
 public void uploadFile() throws IOException, ServletException{

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();


    Part filePart = request.getPart("item");
    String filename = getFilename(filePart);
    InputStream filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

    //persist the data here

}
```

when trying to run it on the server, of course there is the error message: "PWC4016: Request.getPart is called without multipart configuration. Either add a @MultipartConfig to the servlet, or a multipart-config element to web.xml"

But I don't know where to put this annotation, neither do I have the name of the jsf generated servlet of my managed bean so I can't put it into the web.xml neither.
Is it generally a bad idea to put this routine into a managed bean or should I stick to the servlet variant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@MultipartConfig` basically needs to be put on the `FacesServlet`. You can't do it yourself, but this is already done for [the upcoming JSF 2.2](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#802), complete with a new standard `<h:inputFile>` component with ajax support, see also [JSF spec issue 802](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-802).

Until then, your best bet is grabbing a 3rd party component library or homebrewing a custom component.

- [Tomahawk `<t:inputFileUpload>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_inputFileUpload.html) - see also [JSF 2.0 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload/5424229#5424229)
- [PrimeFaces `<p:fileUpload>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf) - see also [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked/8880083#8880083)
- Custom `<x:inputFile>` - see also [Uploading files with JSF 2.0 and Servlet 3.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html)

Comment: currently I'm using JUpload Applet for upload files, so uploading is not the problem. It's rather that processing the upload with a managed beans seems not possible at the moment

Comment: If the source is not a JSF view, why do you need a JSF model then? Indeed just use a simple servlet then. Even with JSF 2.2 it would not be (nicely) possible.

Comment: Since I have a file downloadlink in my jsf and a managedbean which serves the file to download (according to your post at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3428207/1644061) ) I thought it would be a good idea to put the upload routine also in this bean. But I think thats the wrong decision right?

Comment: Depends on whether JSF is absolutely mandatory to serve the file. For example, you need to download the file by a JSF POST request instead of a simple GET request because there are some input fields involved for which you'd like to perform JSF validation and so on.