# Get file url in JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, openfiledialog

I am trying to make an openfiledialog in the backing bean, so that I can get the url of the local file. However it seems that the standard JSF library does not support open/save file dialog. Is there another way of getting an url of a file with something similar to openfiledialog?

Here is what has to happen:
Click on a button --> send action to the backing bean --> **show openfiledialog --> get url of the file** --> add url of the file to a list of strings.

I am not sure how to accomplish the bold steps above. Is there someone who can give me any leads or help  to accomplish this?

*(I am using JSF & Primefaces, I would prefer not to use another external library if possible.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using JSF 2.2 as well as Primefaces, why not use the primefaces component itself?

Below is the [Primefaces 5.0 showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml) for a basic file upload:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

    <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadView.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"/>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{fileUploadView.upload}" disabled="true" />
</h:form>
```

**Managed Bean**

```
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
public class FileUploadView {

    private UploadedFile file;

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void upload() {
        if(file != null) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        }
    }
}
```

The `enctype` attribute for the form is required. Also, for using Primefaces file upload, you need to setup certain context parameters and filters. You may refer the appropriate [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) for the same.

Comment: Not entirely what I ment, but I get the idea! Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can get url for file uploaded to path or database, not sure if you make a search in google but I found these URLs maybe will help you:

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html

[Download a file with JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428039/download-a-file-with-jsf)

You just need to open a dialog have link of file, or maybe file url can be stored in variable to add to list too or what ever you want.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Both these links will give information about how to download a file, of which the location is known. What I am trying to accomplish is a file search and store the url/location of the file into a variable (Thus the location is now known on forehand)