# rich:modalPanel doesn't show up anymore if h:commandButton was clicked

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

First of all, this issue is on Edge only, everything works just fine on Chrome and Firefox.

I'm working with JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.3.3.Final (with community fix for IE9+).

I have a `rich:modalPanel` which is opened by a `a4j:commandButton`. On the modal panel there is a `h:commandButton` which hides the modal panel and exports a pdf generated with jasperReports. My issue is that after exporting a file for the first time, the modal panel doesn't show up anymore. I have to reload the page and then it works again. There's nothing new in console when I press `a4j:commandButton` to open the modal panel, the last log is "HTML1300: Navigation occured." which comes from pressing `h:commandButton`.

Open modal panel (contents.jspx) - sets `printBean.showModalPanel` to `true`:

```
<a4j:commandButton
    image="/img/print.gif"
    styleClass="clsCursorPointer"
    action="#{ printBean.onExportReport}"
    ajaxSingle="true"
    reRender="printConfirmationPanel" />
```

Modal panel (forms.jspx):

```
<h:panelGroup id="printConfirmationPanel" >
    <rich:modalPanel id="printConfirmationMP"
        autosized="true"
        showWhenRendered="true"
        rendered="#{ printBean.showModalPanel}" >
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin: auto">
                <h:commandButton id="confirmButton"             <--- Export button
                    value="#{ msgs['printButton']}"
                    actionListener="#{ printBean.onExportButton}" >

                    <f:attribute name="format" value="PDF"/>
                    (more attributes)
                </h:commandButton>

                <rich:componentControl
                    attachTo="confirmButton"
                    for="printConfirmationMP"
                    operation="hide"
                    event="onclick" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </rich:modalPanel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: can you please post the code of the `printBean.onExportButton` method.

Comment: also i found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639352/downloading-a-file-using-jsf). also since I don't know the richfaces library not that well, please try downloading the file not via ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by updating Edge to version 81.0.416.53.