# Show an InputStream as dynamic image in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, inputstream, omnifaces, graphicimage

How can we embed and show an `InputStream` as dynamic image in JSF 2.0 with OmniFaces?

Answer (score 2):

OmniFaces does not offer any utility for this — yet.

If the image files are located on the disk file system, then you need to create a virtual context in the servletcontainer configuration so that they can be accessed by a normal URL. See also [Load images from outside of webapps / webcontext / deploy folder using <h:graphicImage> or <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-images-from-outside-of-webapps-webcontext-deploy-folder-using-hgraphi).

If the image files are stored in the DB, then you need to create a simple servlet which just writes the `InputStream` of the image from the DB to the `OutputStream` of the HTTP response. See also [How to retrieve and display images from a database in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page) (note that this doesn't require JSP/HTML, you can as good just use `<h:graphicImage>` as it merely generates a HTML `<img>` element).

There's the PrimeFaces `<p:graphicImage>`, but this is a bit unintuitive to implement. See also [Display dynamic image from database with p:graphicImage and StreamedContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-dynamic-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage-and-streamedcontent).

---

**Update**: since OmniFaces 2.0 (for JSF 2.2) there's a [`<o:graphicImage>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage) component which supports among others directly referencing a `byte[]` or `InputStream` property in an `@ApplicationScoped` managed bean in an intuitive way like below:

```
<o:graphicImage value="#{imageStreamer.getById(bean.imageId)}" />
```

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ImageStreamer {

    @Inject
    private ImageService service;

    public InputStream getById(Long id) { // byte[] is also supported.
        return service.getContent(id);
    }

}
```

In contrary to PrimeFaces `<p:graphicImage>`, no `<f:param>` is needed and the EL method arguments are evaluated during render response phase, but the EL method itself is only invoked when the browser actually requests the image. See also [the showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage) and [the blog on the subject](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2014/11/omnifaces-20-released.html).