# JSF File Download Chooser

Tags: java, jsf, tomahawk

In any of the JSF libraries, is there any component which works just opposite to [`<t:inputFileUpload>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_inputFileUpload.html), to select the folder (@ client machine) and download a predefined file from the server to client machine's selected folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the browser that shows the browse dialog whenever there's a file it cannot handle.

And files it can't handle are determined by the Content-type. So set your `Content-Type`, `Content-Disposition` and the likes headers for a specific resource, and add a link to that resource.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914025/forcing-a-save-as-dialogue-from-any-web-browser-from-jsf-application/2914079#2914079)  has an example.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give url to `File` in `<a>`  tag if it is in public space